# Learning or preparing a spell over Telepathic Bond?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, wizard

Just wondering...

Would a [telepathic bond](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/telepathicBond.htm) spell cast on my helper npc (another wizard of equal or greater level; stationed in a magic library) allow them to "stream" my spellbook's contents to me as if I was reading it when resetting daily spells?

If I keep the spellbook instead, would I be able to have the helper stare at books in order to add new spells to the spellbook?

My reasoning is the spell text does not clarify what can be exchanged over the *telepathic bond* that links the creatures:

> The creatures can communicate telepathically through the bond
>   regardless of language.

This boils down to what de definition of telepathic communication is in D&D.
If a telepathic communication can transmit concepts/memories/images I would say it can be used to like I described...

Comment: well permanency is not really a focal point of the question... so I will remove it. As for the version I am playing both editions so I would like to know if the answers is different between them

Comment: OK, we need the edition comparison tag then

Comment: It might be better to ask this question separately for each edition (i.e. edit this question to focus just on 3.5e, given the 3.5e SRD link, and ask about 5e separately). That way, you may get higher-quality answers, each focused on a single edition. The rules of each edition are very different.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will ask for 5e as a follow up question by referring to this one. I was thinking it may boil down to the definition of _telepathic communication_  indeed...

Answer (score 2):

### No

*Telepathic Bond* allows telepathic communication- it doesn’t allow you to see what they see.

Since you can’t “stream” using verbal communication, you can’t using telepathic communication.

Comment: This reminds me of a manager class communication exercise where you have to only verbally explain to someone how to do a thing without you being able to see what they are doing for corrections... usually ends up terribly wrong.

Comment: @Slagmoth you should definiately play [Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes](https://keeptalkinggame.com/) - one of you has the bomb and the other has the disposal manual.

Answer (score 1):

As for 3.5, there is no "official" ruling that I can find.

The real debate comes in as to the limits of the *telepathic bond*.  It allows "communication" between each end, but RAW the telepathy ability monsters have simply means you are transmitting something like linguistic communication (i.e. telepathy lets certain monsters communicate with creatures that have a language of some kind).

Another limitation is that spells are NOT written in plain language: they are somewhat "encrypted" by each individual wizard.  In fact, you can't actually just pick up and read another wizard's spellbook like you do something written in another language.  You are required to make Spellcraft checks to decode each specific spell (and failing the check means you can't even try to learn that spell until you raise your Spellcraft skill by at least 1 point, not even if you use a different book or scroll), or you have to use the spell *read magic* to automatically decipher the spell for you.

Since there is no real official answer (unless someone can quote a Sage Advice dealing with it), then my answer as a DM would be that you might can try this only under very specific circumstances.  The helper has to be a wizard (since that class is the only one that even understands why a spellbook is written a given way), the helper has to make a Spellcraft check to attempt to "explain" the spell to you (DC 10 + spell level x 3, rolling 1 burns out that slot for the day), and it potentially takes longer to memorize spells this way (10 minutes per spell slot level, 5 minutes for a 0-level spell slot).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.